# Slick Slider - Big Space UNDER slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I have "slick slider" working and it is responsive but there is a HUGE space under the slider.

The space seems to be caused by the ".slick-list" class.
I made ".slick-list" red so it would show up easily.

No matter what I do I cant get that space to go away.

There is No padding on this element, no margin, no border...

Any tips?

The page test page is here:
[slider test page](http://www.videolinktech.com/slider-test/slick.htm)

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar issue, although I wouldn't call the gap underneath "huge".

I resolved it by setting the line-height of slick-slider to 0.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with my spacing issue.

Comment: Helped me too. I wonder why a line-height was causing the gap, though? The content in my slides are just images set to display as blocks..

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

In the slick css the class .slick-slide had a height set of 100%

So by default the slides were all 100% of the page.

I removed height:100% and the big space was gone.

Answer (score 0):

need to override this style element that is set by style.css using !important

```
 .image{
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: none; <-- currently the value is center center. 
  background-size:100%;
  height:0;width:100%;
  padding-bottom:50%;
  }
```

Comment: I changed background-position from "center center" TO " none" but that did not make the big red space go away.    It did not make any difference so I changed it back...    that big red space is from the slick-list class from slick.css

Comment: @KennyJohnson have you found any solution to this? I'm having the same issue